# Procedure em Firebird com C#

Tags: c#, firebird

Caros, boa noite

Sou novo em Firebird, apesar de já ter mexido algumas vezes com ele, mas nada profissional, porém agora devido a uma necessidade a solução Embedded foi definida para uso.

Pois bem, estou desenvolvendo uma interface de gravação de usuários com Stored Procedure pelo IBExpert, quando executo o código neste ambiente o retorno é zero tal como definido, porém na aplicação (windows.forms com C#) chamando a procedure pelo método ExecuteScalar ou ExecuteNonQuery o retorno que surge é -1

Algum abençoado poderia iluminar esta pessoa? Queria entender o motivo do retorno ser -1 e não 0 como definido.

(Abaixo o código da procedure)

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE IDB_SP_USU_GRAVA_USUARIO (
 in_usu_id integer,
 in_usu_log varchar(50),
 in_usu_pwd varchar(80),
 in_usu_nam varchar(80),
 in_usu_sta char(1),
 in_usu_dta_val date,
 in_prf_id integer)
 returns ( msg_ret integer )
 as
 BEGIN
 if ( :IN_USU_ID = 0 ) then in_usu_id = NULL;
 if ( ( :in_usu_dta_val < current_date) or (:in_usu_dta_val IS NULL)) then    IN_USU_DTA_VAL = dateadd(year, 1, current_date);

UPDATE or INSERT INTO idb_tb_usu_usuarios
    (usu_id, usu_log, usu_pwd, usu_nam, usu_sta, prf_id, usu_dta_inc, usu_dta_fin)
VALUES
    (:IN_USU_ID, :IN_USU_LOG, :IN_USU_PWD, :IN_USU_NAM, :IN_USU_STA, :IN_PRF_ID, CURRENT_DATE, :IN_USU_DTA_VAL);
MSG_RET = sqlcode;

END
```